# Dynamically generate access_token to fetch page or group post

Tags: facebook, access-token

I am creating a magazine in my site thatI needed to get the post of users from their groups and page. The API for it requires the access token to get the required data.
I need to generate the access token for the user which required APP key and secret.
But what if the user has not created any APP and they just want to get the post from their page or group, as most of the normal users do not create any APP.
So is their any way I can fetch their group or page post easily or can get the access token for the user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the app for your site. This way, you have the required key and secret to generate an access token, and you can fetch content for your users. No need for your users to create an app :-)